# accessing local variable on global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, local-storage

I have the following code, It tells that when the submit button is pressed, hide the filterlist and add a variable in localstorage refering to the closeded filterlist and submit the form in the end. All this logic will happen if the browser window size less than 768px (Mobile Size)

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    var $target, $form, $filterList;
    $(".f-f .f-ft [type='submit']").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $form = $($target.parents("form")[0]);
        $filterList = $form.find(".f-inp");

        $filterList.hide();
        localStorage.setItem("FilterList", "closed");
        $form.submit();
    });
    localStorage.getItem("FilterList") === "closed" ? $filterList.hide() : $filterList.show();
} else {
    $(".filter").on("click", function(event) {
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
            $form = $($target.parents("form")[0]);

        $form.submit();
    });
}
```

My question is how to access the variable $filterList with its new value outside (on click) method?
Are there any other ways to using localstorage?

Comment: By defining `var $filterList;` in the global scope, and by not using `var` inside the onclick method like you do, the variable will be accessible at the global scope. See also: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: I'm not defining the variable inside on click method, but inside if statement

Comment: Yes, I see, so when that `if` statement is at the global scope then so will `$filterList` be.

Comment: I think it is, it is on the global scope if I'm not wrong

Comment: Just move `var $filterList;` outside of the `if` statement and the problem is sorted.  When you want to check if it has been set to something you can use 'if ($filterList) { ... }'

Comment: I moved tha variable outside if statement and I got the following error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $filterList is not defined

Comment: Define it outside of *all* your code blocks